# What type of index to create?

Tags: sql-server, indexing, partitioning

I have a database that contains a table partitioned across five filegroups based on the TransactionType field.

The structure of the table  :

```
ID              --> BIGINT
Account         --> BIGINT
Amount          --> DECIMAL
TransactionType --> INT
TransactionDate --> Date
```

My table contains also the following indexes :

```
PK_Table1       --> Clustered, primary key  --> ID, TransactionType
IX_Account      --> Nonclustered            --> Account
IX_Type         --> Nonclustered            --> TransactionType 
IX_Date         --> NonClustered            --> TransactionDate
IX_Amount       --> Nonclustered            --> Amount
```

My question is, which index should I build as aligned and which index should I leave as not aligned ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Microsoft, an aligned index is an index that is built on the same partition scheme as its corresponding table. When a table and its indexes are in alignment, SQL Server can switch partitions quickly and 
efficiently while maintaining the partition structure of both the table and its indexes.

An index does not have to participate in the same named partition function to be aligned  with its base table. However, the partition function of the index and the base table 
must be essentially the same, in that:

1. The arguments of the partition functions have the same data
   type.
2. They define the same number of partitions.
3. They define the same boundary values for partitions.

A non-aligned index is an index partitioned independently from its corresponding table. That is, the index has a different partition scheme or is placed on a separate filegroup from the base table. 
Designing an non-aligned partitioned index can be useful in the following cases:

1. The base table has not been partitioned.
2. The index key is unique and it does not contain the partitioning
   column of the table.
3. You want the base table to participate in collocated joins with more
   tables using different join columns.

So the answer to your question :
- Make IX_Type an aligned index because it's based on the partitioning key.
- Make the rest of indexes as a non-aligned indexe.

Comment: I understand the reason why to make IX_TYPE as an aligned index.